# How to hit 2 API, get and post method in react js

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, axios

for getting data from subscribers API we need to hit another login API that has a username password and access token. *emphasized text*

Comment: I will explain the question here. Need to get data from Subscribers API, in order to get data from it, another Login API must be hit which has username password and access token. Subscribers API has to get method and LOGIN API has post method. This shall be done in react js

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.